# How to write special characters in vb.net console

Tags: vb.net

How do i output special characters to the console in visual basic. because simply putting console.writeline("Copyright symbol") outputs a C instead of the symbol. how can i fix this.

Comment: this isnt a duplicate honostly. i just want to know if it works for all characters not just the copyright.

Comment: The console has to be using a font which has glyphs for all the characters you want to display. It shouldn't take you long to write a small program to test that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `ChrW()` function with the Unicode decimal value of the symbol you want to print, for the Copyright symbol it is 169.

```
console.writeline(ChrW(169))
```

You can find the Unicode decimal values for other symbols on [this website](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/a9/index.htm).

Answer (score 0):

The real copyright symbol is a unicode character. Use `\u00A9` instead of C to print it out correctly.